# Openpyxl to write in a single cell

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using `openpyxl` to write data in specific cells and not in rows by using the append function.
What is the method ?

I already tried using the following snippet:

```
variable = wb2s1.append(row = 4, column = 2)

variable = wb2s1.cell(row = 4, column = 2)

variable = wb2s1.cell(row = 4, column = 2).value
```

But nothing works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Accessing cells is covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
wb2s1.append({'A' : 'This is A1', 'C' : 'This is C1'})
```

From the source code(http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append):

```
def append(self, list_or_dict):
    """Appends a group of values at the bottom of the current sheet.

    * If it's a list: all values are added in order, starting from the first column
    * If it's a dict: values are assigned to the columns indicated by the keys (numbers or letters)

    :param list_or_dict: list or dict containing values to append
    :type list_or_dict: list/tuple or dict

    Usage:

    * append(['This is A1', 'This is B1', 'This is C1'])
    * **or** append({'A' : 'This is A1', 'C' : 'This is C1'})
    * **or** append({0 : 'This is A1', 2 : 'This is C1'})
```

Edit: Use official documentation site

```
difference = (cost_with - cost_without)/100

if b == 1:
    max_difference = difference
    currentRow = ['PV Size' + ' ' + str(size), difference]
else:
    currentRow.append(difference)

if max_difference > difference:
    max_difference = difference

if b==6:
   wb2s1.append(currentRow)
```

Comment: I couldnt get it. Where do I specifiy the row number and column number and the variable to be written on. Im sorry Im new to programming and i thought this simple task would be easy to implement.

Comment: For append, you don't specify a row number. You just fill each row (with nothing if you want) one after another. If you want to edit only some cells, don't use append.

Comment: ok but is it possible to fill a few cells in the row in steps and then specify to append when to shift to the next row ? or any other function apart from append ?

Comment: Yes, make a dictionary with the cells you want to fill in the current row and call append on it. Then make an other dictionary with the values for the next row, call append on it, and so on.

Comment: so now i am making a dynamic dictionary with size b. after each iteration until b it adds the variable difference to the dictionary and then in the last iteration i call append. something like this data = {difference: b}
            if b==6:
                wb2s1.append([data.values]) could u plz tell me the fault ?

Comment: @Abdur Please add your current code at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score -1):

difference = (cost_with - cost_without)/100

```
        if b ==1:
            max_difference = difference

        if max_difference > difference:
            max_difference = difference

        wb2s1.append(['PV Size' + ' ' + str(size), difference])
        data = {difference}

        if b==6:
           wb2s1.append([data])
```

Comment: so there are 6 iterations before the calculation of difference. each iteration calculates a new value of difference which i like to add to the dict and finally write it after the 6th iteration

Comment: wb2s1.append(['PV Size' + ' ' + str(size), difference]) -> wb2s1.append(['PV Size' + ' ' + str(size), str(difference)])

Comment: You want to write the six values on the same row? Do you want to write max_difference somewhere?

Comment: Please add four spaces at the beginning of your answer for code formatting.

Comment: so i do the complete claculation. result is stored in variable difference. i write it into the dictionary (or array right ??) data for six times. The iteration lasts six times. then i write all six values plus the heading on the left side meaning 7 columns with one append comment. i do this for 7 rows

Comment: i suceed in all the parts. Even have a 6 element dictionary called data. but even if i insert this dictionary variable in append it doesnt work.   wb2s1.append(['PV Size' + ' ' + str(b), data])

Comment: the data type are float numbers. i tried everything by converting the dictionary data into a list, tuple etc but i just cant seem to get it to write

Comment: it gives this error. raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert {5: {-76.67546947642579}} to Excel

Comment: I add new code that should work at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: thank you so much. its working now. apparently i wasnt adding data correctly to the list. have a nice day and thanks a lot !!!!!!!!!!